# I have a button in my header but still after having just 1 button it is showing 2 buttons

Tags: html, css

So actually i was just doing my web and now what suddenly happened was that there was another button in my header section whereas i have just 1 button in my button division.

I tried removing that button from there but still the other button having `Our Apps` as the text is appearing. I have that button in the code but it is just nowhere around it. Also nothing matches in between both of the button. Currently I havent tried anything else i dont have any clue about it. Here is the code-

```css
#clickhere {
  border: 2 px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 62 % ;
  left: 50 % ;
  transform: translate(-50 % , -50 % );
  padding: 5 px;
  border-radius: 5 px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18 px;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  transition: 0.6 s ease;
}

#clickhere: hover {
  color: grey;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 20 px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <button id="clickhere">READ MORE</button>
</div>
```

The result is supposed to be just one button like this.
[Link To Image](https://ibb.co/MSsWT8Y)

Comment: your code showing only 1 button. What's wrong with that? can you edit with the image of the problem and full code ?

Comment: can you post 'Our App' button style and HTML

Comment: make sure id `clickhere` is unique. Not assigned to other element. And check class `btn`

Comment: I had mentioned that even if i remove the button the other button is not getting removed. Also i mentioned that my id clickhere is specific to that only along with the class `btn`.

Comment: Can you provide the actual demo. I can only see 1 button

Comment: [This is the real result](https://ibb.co/XzvMxy0)

Comment: instead of image post codes. Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Comment: In codepen it is working fine but not on my PC. Still here is the codepen - 
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XLpvBN)

Comment: Code doesn't write itself. Somewhere you must have the extra code for the button "READ MORE". It is not present it what you have shown to us.

Comment: Sorry but it is happening. I cant figure it out. I just edited the codepen and the double button is appearing. It is pretty long code because when i didnt add the full code i wasnt getting that button.

Comment: your code having only one button. whats the problem?

Comment: My code has 1 button (In the header). Where as it is showing 2 (Have a look at the codepen which i just updated).

Comment: Its the 'OUR APPS' button, from the `#division3` div.

Comment: How can i make it appear on its desired location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave both the `#clickhere` and the `#OurApps` buttons an absolute position, while never using a relative position on parent elements. This means both buttons are absolute placed on the page. Which means they get placed on top of each other, as they share the same css rules.